# Todas las combinaciones wildcard

Tags: java, string, regex, recursión

estoy haciendo un programa que lea un string por teclado que tenga 1,0 y x.
La idea es que imprima todas las combinaciones posibles de 0 y 1 reemplazandolos en donde iba la x en el string inicial, en orden ascendente.
Lo estoy haciendo con una función que se llama a si misma.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n = reader.nextLine();
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<n.length() ; i++){ //cuenta todos los x en el string
        if(n.charAt(i)=='x'){
            cont++;
        }
    }
    cont = (int)Math.pow(2,cont); //cantidad de combinaciones de x
    imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(n,cont);
    
}

static void imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(String n,int cont){
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\x.*");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(n);
    if(mat.matches()){
        imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(n.replace('x','0'),cont-1);
        imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(n.replace('x','1'),cont-1);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(n);
    }




}
```

}

Pero solo imprime los extremos de todas las combinaciones, osea ceros y unos.
No entiendo como hacer que imprima todos los casos posible que serian n = 2^cant_de_combinaciones_x

Por ejemplo: Si entra un String 1x01x1x deberia imprimir todos los casos en diferentes string 1**0**01**0**1**0** , 1**0**01**0**1**1** , 1**0**01**1**1**0**, y asi hasta imprimir 1**1**01**1**1**1**

Comment: puedes editar la pregunta poniendo lo que debe salir

Comment: *String.replace()* reemplaza TODAS las ocurrencias del caracter indicado. Además, la expresión parece incorrecta.

Comment: Entiendo, desconocía que es lo que hacia exactamente gracias por la aclaración. Ahora me apareció otro problema lo dejo como respuesta lo que tengo.

Answer (score 1):

Al final gracias a la acotación en los comentarios de como funcionaba el método replace y modificar el código logre dar con la solución.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n = reader.nextLine();
    imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(n);
    
}

static void imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(String n){
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\x.*");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(n);


    if(mat.matches()){

        imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(n.replaceFirst("\\x","0"));
        imprimirTodasLasCombinaciones(n.replaceFirst("\\x","1"));

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(n);
    }

}
```